# Javascript does not recognise dynamic div content

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

I have a script i have been battling with now for like a week.

I have a page which has a div with id ("content"). Now I loaded some content, a form contained in a div tag to be specific, into this div VIA Ajax, and it is displaying fine

Now, the challenge is - When the form is submitted, Im am calling a function that will disable all the field on the element in that div tag. I always get the error "undefined".

It seems that the div, that i brought in to the page isn't recognized by javascript..

I have searched google, bing, yahoo..i just havent found the solution yet...

Please, what do I do??

I have included the code below --

+++++++++
The code below for my external javascript file

++++++++++++++++++++

```
// JavaScript Document

var doc = document;
var tDiv;
var xmlHttp;
var pgTitle;

function getXMLObj(){
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
          // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                Obj = new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else if (window.ActiveXObject){
            // code for IE6, IE5
                Obj = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
        else{
                alert("Your browser does not support Ajax!");
        }
        return Obj;
}


function loadCont(toLoad, view){
    doc.getElementById('loadBlank').innerHTML = '<div id="loading">Processing Request...</div>';
    var url;
    switch(toLoad){
        case 'CI':
            pgTitle = "Administration - Company Information";
            url = "comp_info.php?v=" + view + "&sid=" + Math.random();
            break;
        case 'JB':
            pgTitle = "Administration - Jobs";
            url = "jobs.php?v=" + view + "&sid=" + Math.random();
            break;
        case 'US':
            pgTitle = "Administration - Users";
            url = "users.php?v=" + view + "&sid=" + Math.random();
            break;
        case 'EP':
            pgTitle = "Administration - Employees";
            url = "emp.php?v=" + view + "&sid=" + Math.random();
            break;
        case 'AP':
            pgTitle = "Administration - Recruitments";
            url = "applicants.php?v=" + view + "&sid=" + Math.random();
            break;
        case 'JV':
            pgTitle = "Administration - Recruitments";
            url = "jobvacancy.php?v=" + view + "&sid=" + Math.random();
            break;
    }

    xmlHttp = getXMLObj();
    if (xmlHttp !== null && xmlHttp !== undefined){
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = loadingContent;
            xmlHttp.open('GET', url, true);
            xmlHttp.send(null);
    }
}

function loadingContent(){

    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 || xmlHttp.readyState == 'complete'){
            //Show the loading and the title, but hide the content...
            if (xmlHttp.status == 200){
                doc.getElementById('dMainContent').innerHTML = parseScript(xmlHttp.responseText);
                doc.getElementById('loadBlank').innerHTML = '';
            }
            else{
                doc.getElementById('dMainContent').innerHTML = 'Sorry..Page not available at this time. <br />Please try again later';
                doc.getElementById('loadBlank').innerHTML = '';
            }
    }
    if (xmlHttp.readyState < 4){
            //Show the loading and the title, but hide the content...
            doc.getElementById('ActTitle').innerHTML = pgTitle;
            doc.getElementById('dMainContent').innerHTML = '';
    }
}

function valCompInfo(){
    //First Disable All the elements..
    alert('I was hree');
    DisEnaAll('CompForm');
    //Now..lets validate the entries..
}

function DisEnaAll(contId){
    //alert(doc.getElementById(contId).elements);
    var theId = doc.getElementById(contId).elements;

    try{
        var numElems = theId.length;

        for (var i=0; i < (numElems - 1); i++){
            (theId[i].disabled == false) ? (theId[i].disabled = true) : (theId[i].disabled = false);                
        }
    }
    catch(e){
        var msg = "The following error occurred: \n\n";
        msg += e.description
        alert(msg); 
    }

}


// http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=138830
function parseScript(_source) {
    var source = _source;
    var scripts = new Array();

    // Strip out tags
    while(source.indexOf("<script") > -1 || source.indexOf("</script") > -1) {
        var s = source.indexOf("<script");
        var s_e = source.indexOf(">", s);
        var e = source.indexOf("</script", s);
        var e_e = source.indexOf(">", e);

        // Add to scripts array
        scripts.push(source.substring(s_e+1, e));
        // Strip from source
        source = source.substring(0, s) + source.substring(e_e+1);
    }

    // Loop through every script collected and eval it
    for(var i=0; i<scripts.length; i++) {
        try {
            eval(scripts[i]);
        }
        catch(ex) {
            // do what you want here when a script fails
        }
    }

    // Return the cleaned source
    return source;
 }
```

This code is on the main page where the javascript is

```
<div id="dMainContent">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And finally, the content of the page i am loading via ajax..

```
<div style="width:738px" id="CompForm">
    <div class="tdright">
        <a href="#" class="lnkBtn" onclick="valCompInfo();"><?php echo $btnNm; ?></a> &nbsp;
     </div>
</div>
```

That's the code..

Thanks

Comment: post the code please.

Comment: May be me, but I have never seen the property *elements* of a dom node `var theId = doc.getElementById(contId).elements;` ; is that in the w3 specification?

Comment: take care not to mix C#.net stuff into your JavaScript

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with div tag (id "CompForm") which is not a HTML form.

"elements" is a collection of the form element not div element. So when trying to access div.elements the property is undefined.

See MSDN, form.elements is part of DOM level 1 (according to MSDN)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537449%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks..this reply was very helpful..But i want to add this..
Lets even agree that the "element" is a collection of the form elements, why is it that the div (with id - 'compForm'), that i used Ajax to load into the innerHTML of the other div (with id - 'dMainContent'), i cannot access that div from my javascript code?
Why does it return null??

Thanks..

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question completely, but I believe it is because the id need to be 'CompForm' not 'compForm' when used with document.getElementById(). It is case sensitive and it should match with what is in the HTML. And of course you need to be sure the 'CompForm' div tag is already added to the DOM first.

Answer (score 0):

Add your Javascript functions or external JS file to the original page.

Comment: Yeah, I have done that already..
Now when i call a fucntion contained in the external script, it works fine, but stops when the function needs or come accross an element from the content i load in through ajax

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is not JavaScript....

```
doc.getElementById(contId).elements
```

but is used in your JavaScript... you will definitely not get anything. (null)

I don't think this is valid either:

```
theId[i].disabled == false
```

Comment: At the top of the page..in the javascript file content, I had already declared doc = document; This is because i dont like typing in "document" all the type..its pretty long for my likening

Comment: elements or disabled are not a valid methods in the example

Comment: I think elements only work for form elements whereas yours is a DIV. Also disabled only work on form elements like input text box. Example of disable: document.getElementById('aaa').disabled;

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: Note per comments: this is NOT the answer :)  See comments for details of why.

Left as an answer simply as a learning aid aid as suggested.

Shouldn't

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = loadingContent;
```

be

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = loadingContent();
```

or

```
loadingContent();
```

and that function should return a value if you want to assign it like that...

Comment: Well, I dnt really know why but..
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = loadingContent; works. I observed that 
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = loadingContent(); only works if i put it this way..

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = loadingContent(){
  //some content here...
}

But all the same, both works.

I juat dont know why the content i brought in via the ajax cannot be read by the javascript function

Comment: **No, it shound NOT be!**  He's assigning an event handler.

Comment: Yea, I was pretty dumb looking at it that way :(  Perhaps I should just remove this answer...

Comment: I'd edit in a comment to the tune of 'oops' to reduce the chance of down-votes, but your answer is still worthwhile for the learning that you -and I- were able to take from it. :)